# c# update object from another object of same type ignoring null values

Tags: c#

I have an Object A and an Object B of the same Type.  How would I update A's properties to B's non-null properties, keeping the state of A's properties that B doesn't change.

The object may have properties that are complex object themselves and I dive into them and update those properties as well.

here is some pseudo code for you to get the idea.  the only problem is some properties are complex objects that may also have properties, so im pretty sure i need recursion.

```
T obj1 = new T();
T obj2 = new T();
var properties = Type.GetType("T").GetProperties();

foreach(var item in properties)
{   
     if(item != null)
     {

     }

}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same task as in the marked duplicate. If you have some _specific_ problem implementing your own scenario using the answer in the duplicate, please post a new question, being sure to include a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, along with a clear and detailed explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I'm not sure that thread qualify as duplicate, are you sure ?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, yes i'm agreeing with you, due i didn't quite knew if that minor change is qualifying it as still similar to duplicate. Anyway it's a fine line and i also believe the OP can manage the change.

Comment: @OrelEraki: okay. and sorry...I didn't notice you're not the same user who posted this question. the wording of my comment replying to yours wasn't quite right, sorry if it was confusing.